# New to php loadHTML error 500

Tags: php, html, load, getelementbyid

I'm totally new to php.

Running this code (that I found in SO) I receive Error 500 when the 4th line is executed:

```
$html = $data->saveHTML();
```

What is wrong with this code? 
Do I have to declare something within php.ini so that the code can run?

```
<?php

$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('aTest.html');

$data = $dom->getElementById("someDiv");
$html = $data->saveHTML();

echo $html;
?>
```

And the web page is in the same folder (I use IIS7 with php):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <META NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
    <TITLE>Test</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
        <div id="someDiv">
            Hello World!
        </div>
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DOMElement` has no `saveHTML` method.  That is a [method of `DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).

```
$data = $dom->getElementById("someDiv");
$html = $dom->saveHTML($data);
```

You should consider turning error reporting on while in development.

Answer (score -2):

May be try this.It may help you.

```
$html = $data->saveHTML($dom);
```

Comment: This would give you the whole document as it was before.